# Как сериализовать форму в Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs

Когда на странице может быть несколько форм? Какую лучший путь сделать это?
Как вариант для каждой формы указать:

```
<form ng-submit="submitForm('type')">
```

Тогда как вызвать этот сабмит по кнопке `<div class="btn save">Save</div>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет необходимости в серилизации форм. Ваши данные хранятся в скопе и синхронизируются через директиву `ngModel`.

Вот пример:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div data-ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl">
      <form name="parentForm">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="ctrl.formData.field1" />
        <form name=childForm">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="ctrl.formData.field2" />
      </form>
      </form>
     <form name="siblingForm">
       <input type="text" data-ng-model="ctrl.formData.field3" />
     </form>

      {{ctrl.formData}}
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

```js
angular.module('app', [])
       .controller('AppCtrl', function(){
         var ctrl = this;

         ctrl.formData = {};
       });
```

Comment: Ну а если несколько форм на одной странице?

Comment: то же самое, главное чтобы все формы  были внутри объявления контроллера `data-ng-controller="AppCtrl as ctrl"` или можно разбить на несколько контроллеров, которые будут вложены в "главный" контроллер, который в свою очередь соберет все данные и отправит их.

Comment: Мне нужно чтобы в одном контроллере было несколько форм